# Run a regression of countries by quartiles for a specific year

Tags: stata

I am exploring an effect that I think will vary by GDP levels, from a data set that has, vertically, country and year (1960 to 2015), so each country label is on 55 rows. I ran

```
sort year
by year: egen yrank = xtile(rgdp), nquantiles(4)
```

which tags every year row with what quartile of GDP they were in that year. I want to run this:

```
xtreg fiveyearg taxratio if yrank == 1 & year==1960
```

which would regress my variable (tax ratio) against some averaged gdp data from countries that were in the bottom quartile of GDPs in 1960 alone. So even if later on they grew enough to change ranks, the later data would still be in the regression pool. Sadly, I cannot get this code, or any variation, to run.

My current approach is to try to generate some new variable that would give every row with country label X a value of 1 if they were in the bottom quartile in 1960, but I can't get that to work either. i have run out of ideas, so I thought I would ask!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by " i cannot get this code, or any variation, to run" ? Please report exact errors if any, or undesired behavior.

Comment: The error i get from that specific code is "no observations", since the syntax is not correct. in this case, the exact errors are not really the question, its "how would someone go about setting up such a variable". i honestly imagine none of my code is too relevant, but i tried to include some for completeness sake.

it seems like perhaps this is not what the forum is for? Thats fine, im sorry to be in the wrong place, i definitely did not mean any offense/misuse anyone's time. ill try to ask more forum appropriate questions in the future

Comment: The restriction `year == 1960` does what it implies. Try `list fiveyearg taxratio if yrank == 1 & year==1960` to see how small is the subset you select. See http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055 for some technique.

Comment: Forum conventions include a preference for concise statement and  orthodox punctuation and spelling. Salutations and personal comments are not needed.

Comment: The code you execute and the exact results it produces are usually, if not always, relevant. It is a programming forum, after all. This implies you tried to do something in some programming language, and it resulted in some error or unexpected behavior. Reporting _exactly_ what happened helps with diagnosis and improves the quality of advice you receive; this is true or **any** forum. The down-vote wasn't mine, but I would agree on the original question being easily improved.

Comment: Re: Nick; Thank you for the link! That does contain a lot of useful techniques. While i understand year ==1960, the "insufficient obs" is because it isnt doing what i hoped it would do. The code tries to regress only the rows year = 1960 with the yrank of 1, when what i need to achive is running rows 1960 all the way to 2015, as long as that country (wbcode) had a yrank of 1 on its 1960 row.

And thank you for the advice on the saluations, i will try to be concise over formal in the future.

Comment: That case is covered by my paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your latest comment, which describes the (un)expected behavior:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
country year rank
1 1960 2
1 1961 1
1 1962 2
2 1960 1
2 1961 1
2 1962 1
3 1960 3
3 1961 3
3 1962 3
end

list, sepby(country)

*----- what you want -----

// tag countries whose first observation for -rank- is 1
// (I assume the first observation for -year- is always 1960)
bysort country : gen toreg = rank[1] == 1

list, sepby(country)

// run regression conditional on -toreg-
xtreg ... if toreg
```

Check `help subscripting` if in doubt.